# Can I swap in a 2x Shimano 600 FC-6400 crankset to replace a 3x RX-100 crankset?

Tags: shimano, crankset, bottom-bracket, compatibility

I have a 2x Shimano 600 FC-6400 crankset. Can I just replace the 3x RX-100 crankset with it? Will I need a new BB?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly swap them. They both use a square taper (JIS) bottom bracket but the **axle length is different**.

The 600 Ultegra FC-6400 uses an axle of 113mm for a 68mm shell and of 115mm for a 70mm shell.
(Source: [Shimano EV](https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/ev/FC-6400_BB-6400-0834/EV-FC-6400_BB-6400-0834B.pdf))

The RX100 FC-A550-T uses an axle of 122.5mm.
(Source: [VeloBase](https://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=88042241-BAE6-48CC-A935-2358D9F4FA99&Enum=115&AbsPos=5) and [Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/bbsize.html#rx100))

Comment: Also, I believe the FD and the left shifter are different.